# Unexpected EOF on graphql POST request

Tags: javascript, http-headers, fetch, restify, graphql

I am using the `fetch` api to make a `POST` request sending a `GraphQL`

```
fetch( dbUrl, {
        method : 'post',
        body   : JSON.stringify( {
            graphql : "mutation M {saveUser(name:'Avraam')}"
        } )
    } )
```

On the request body I can see clearly:

[image]

On the server I am using `restify` and I have:

`server.use( restify.bodyParser() );`

and

```
import { GraphQLAnimationSchema } from '../schemas/GraphQLAnimationSchema';

const requestBuilder = query => graphql( GraphQLAnimationSchema, query )

...
...

export default {
    '/data' : {
        post : ( req, res ) => requestHandler( requestBuilder( req.body.graphql ), res )
};
```

The GraphQL response with
`{"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error GraphQL request (1:1) Unexpected EOF\n\n1: \n   ^\n"}]}`

Should I use a specific kind of `Headers`, (I have tried to use various Headers) but it doesnt seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by using `FormData`

```
const data = new FormData()
data.append( 'graphql',  "mutation M {saveUser(name:'Avraam')}" )

fetch( dbUrl, {
        method  : 'post',
        body : data
    } )
```